# How many bytes is an accelerometer reading?

Tags: ios, byte, accelerometer, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know how many bytes an accelerometer reading is in iOS? I want to know this because I'm trying to figure out how much data I can fit into a BLE advertisement. I have read that its just six (2 for each axis) but i did not know if this was just a preference.  I would like to be precise beyond 2 digits if possible because I want to capture micro-movements and really exploit their readings.

Answer (score 1):

So far all more or less modern accelerometers i have seen use 6 bytes (2 per axis) but the bits per value may change. 
MMA8451Q has 6 bytes but 14 bits per value.